# How to access a onetoone values from views in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

So I have a `KeyRequest` Model and a `KeyInstance` model. One `KeyRequest` can only refer to one `KeyInstance`, vise versa. And each `KeyInstance` has an `uuid` and a `status`.
I would like to access that `uuid` and the number of available keys in a `KeyRequest`

Here is my models.py:

```
class KeyInstance(models.Model):

    keyrequest = models.OneToOneField('KeyRequest', verbose_name='Key requests', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='request')

    LOAN_STATUS = (
        ('a', 'Available'),
        ('o', 'On loan'),
        ('r', 'Reserved'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=LOAN_STATUS, help_text='Key availability', verbose_name="Key status", blank=True)

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text="Unique ID for this particular key")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["due_back"]
        permissions = (("can_mark_returned", "Set key as returned"),)

    @property
    def is_overdue(self):
        if self.due_back and date.today() > self.due_back:
            return True
        return False

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object
        """
        return '{1} ({0})'.format(self.id,self.roomkey.room_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Returns the url to access a detail record for this book.
        """
        return reverse('keys',args={'pk':self.id})
```

...

```
class KeyRequest(models.Model):
    """
    Model that will hold the key requests
    """
    roomkey = models.ForeignKey('RoomKey',verbose_name="Room", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object
        """
        return '{2}-{0} ({1})'.format(self.roomkey.room_name, self.date_requested, self.requester)

    def get_absolute_url(self):

        return reverse('key-request-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Here is my views.py:

```
class KeyRequestDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = KeyRequest
    template_name = "catalog/roomkey_request_detail.html"

    def RequestDetail(request):
        num_keyinstances_available = KeyInstance.objects.filter(status__exact='a').count()

        return render(
            request,
            'key-request-detail',
            context = {'num_key_available':num_keyinstances_available},
        )
```

here is my template

```
{{ keyrequest.request.id }}

{{ num_key_available }}
```

Can anyone tell me the proper way to do this?

Comment: Your context is only including  num_key_available, no keyrequest

Comment: Some observations. In your `keyrequest` field of `KeyInstance` model no need for related name. Just do: forward relationships - `keyinstance.keyrequest`; reverse relationship - `keyrequest.keyinstance`

Comment: Also, your view is problematic. What is the purpose of the `RequestDetail` method? I think what you want to override is `get_object`. Take a look at www.ccbv.co.uk or just go ahead and use a function based view. Number of `KeyInstance`is simply `KeyInstance.objects.count()` i.e. The number of such objects

Comment: @Parousia That's actually what I tried at first but it didn't show up on my template...

Comment: @Parousia Thanks I will check out the website for sure, if I wanted to do the `KeyInstance.objects.count()` method how would I pass it into my template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See what you can make of this. I'm sure it will point you in the right direction somehow. Too long for comment section.
Everything inside the context dictionary would be available in your template. You can put as many things as you want inside the context dictionary.

```
class KeyRequestDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = KeyRequest
    template_name = "catalog/roomkey_request_detail.html"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None) # I assume you're using pk to lookup the KeyRequest
        keyrequest_instance = KeyRequest.objects.get(pk=pk)
        # But if there is no such keyrequest instance you have to handle the error somehow

        context = {}
        context['keyrequest'] = keyrequest_instance # the actual keyrequest
        context['num_key_available'] = KeyInstance.objects.filter(status__exact='a').count() # total number of 'available' keys
        key_request_id = keyrequest_instance.keyinstance.id # id of each keyrequest reference from the instance it is tied to
        key_request_status = keyrequest_instance.keyinstance.status # status of each keyrequest reference from the instance it is tied to

        return render(request, "catalog/roomkey_request_detail.html", context)
```

Comment: I'd appreciate if you accept it as answer if it helps you solve the problem. Or you could post your final solution and accept it so that the question has an answer.

Comment: So I did what you did above but then I receive a `Reverse for 'key-request-update' with arguments '('',)' not found. ` I have a `{% url 'key-request-update' keyrequest.pk %} `tag in my template, I tried to add the `pk` into the context dictionary and change `keyrequest.pk ` into `pk` but it is still showing me the error, any inputs why?

Comment: Let's see your url for that view

Comment: here is the url `path('keys/request/<int:pk>/update', views.KeyRequestUpdate.as_view(), name='key-request-update'),`

Comment: The problem is obviously coming from your template. This url expects a primary key but this `{% url 'key-request-update' keyrequest.pk %}` is passing an empty string. So you need to check this `keyrequest.pk`. Does that `keyrequest.pk` actually exist?

Comment: Hmm I'm pretty sure that `keyrequest.pk` does in fact exist because before it was working and I was able to go to the update page.

Comment: I think I see the problem now. This url `{% url 'key-request-update' keyrequest.pk %}` does it have any namespace associated with it? Usually your would have something like this `{% url 'name_space:key-request-update' keyrequest.pk %}` You should define a namespace in your app's urls.py file by doing `app_name = name_space`

Comment: I did that and it's still showing the same issue, do you think there is another way around this ? Also I receive a `'KeyRequest' object has no attribute 'keyinstance'` for this line `key_request_id = keyrequest_instance.keyinstance.id ` for some reason

Comment: For this `'KeyRequest' object has no attribute 'keyinstance'`, just remove the `related_name='request'` from the `keyrequest` field of `KeyInstance` model. After this I would advice you delete your database and migrations. Remake migrations and re migrate.

Comment: Thank you but I kept trying and no matter what I do it keeps coming up with the NoReverseMatch error, do you know why it used to work but now doesn't?

Comment: In your project urls.py you have to do this `from django.urls import include, path`, then `urlpatterns += [path('app-name/', include('app-name.urls')]`. And try to read up on url namespacing https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces